# How to resolve warning "ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute"

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I'm writing test automation in QT. I'am using `QTest::qWaitFor` to wait until the event loop switches to another tab in UI.

```
QTest::qWaitFor([tabs, &currentIdx]() {
    currentIdx = tabs->currentIndex();
    return currentIdx == 1;
}, 5000);
```

Each time I'am using such construction following warning appears:

```
ignoring return value of function declared with 'warn_unused_result' attribute
```

I spent hours dealing with it but no result. I think the problem is the way functions consume returned values from lambda expressions. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You should check return of `qWaitFor` to know if timeout happens.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you very much. With no reason I was sure the warning applies to lambda expression. Handling result of qWaitFor or casting it to void works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is not with lambda, but **your** usage:

You should use/check return value of `qWaitFor` (to know if timeout happens):

```
if (QTest::qWaitFor([tabs, &currentIdx]() {
        currentIdx = tabs->currentIndex();
        return currentIdx == 1;
    }, 5000)) {
    // OK.
    // ...
} else {
    // timeout.
    // ...
}
```